# Get jQuery w/ Android Cordova Links to open in browser

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, hyperlink

I have an Android cordova app, and I use jQuery Mobile for the interface. Basically I am trying to get certian links to open in a browser window instead of cordovas childbrowser.

I have some code here, that I think should work, but i can't seem to debug. Could someone take a look?

http://t.co/kAJ7mrj5

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not certain if this is the problem, I see this attribute:

```
 onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl(http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1703488", {openExternal: true});
```

I think that should be:

```
 onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1703488', {openExternal: true});"
```

Notice the quotes.

Comment: Let me try that out and let you know.

Comment: That wasn't it unfortunately :(

Comment: Sorry, messsed up that comment:

It may be encountering an error, which just stops the Javascript from executing. Try just:  
 onclick="navigator.app.loadUrl('http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1703488')"
If still nothing, I have heard that the first external page will open in the child browser, but if you click an external link within that, then it will open the regular browser.  I'm sure there's a work-around, but I don't know exactly what it is.

And see if that works.

Comment: how to i use the on click with jquery buttons?